# SqlAlchemy inheritance mechanism like Open Object Framework

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, odoo

Newbie here! Here is my question: In `Open Object Framework` that is used by Odoo it is possible for a model to inherit both fields and methods from multiple modules. For example a `Product` model in the context of a Warehouse Management System does not have the same attributes and functionality as a `Product` model in the context of a Sales Management System.
Consider a `Product` model defined in a WMS module and a `Product` model (please note the same name) defined in a SMS module, where the basic attributes and functionality are defined in the `WMS.Product`.
Is it possible to achieve such an inheritance mechanism with SqlAlchemy so that when calling `create_all` the `Product` model that is created contains all the fields and methods that are defined in every module?